# Find and replace string between two documents (more times)

Tags: batch-file

I am new at programming and I wanna make `.bat` script, which take first string from `new.txt`and find it in `text.txt`, then replace it with second string from `new.txt` (there are more than one exact string in this `text.txt`, so script must search whole document).

And then, after search whole document, script take from `new.txt` third string, find it in `text.txt` and replace it with fourth string  from `new.txt`, then find fifth string from `new.txt` and replace it with sixth string etc.

I hope you get it, because my english isn´t good :-) Thanks everyone.

Here are examples my documents, if it helps:

**text.txt:**

```
Ale ne, NE, NE!
Try the tape slot, maybe it's in there.
Try the tape slot, maybe it's in there.
Hey now…
Hey now…
Was it good for you, "Sheriff"?
Next time I'm gonna have to charge you.
BLABLABLA.
Vsadil bych se, ze je tohle skvele misto pro veci, ktere nechces, aby nekdo videl.
Nevedel bych. Byl tady uz kdy jsme se pristehovali, nemam k nemu klic.
BLABLABLA.
```

**new.txt:**

```
BLABLABLA.
BLBBLBBLB.
Ale ne, NE, NE!
But no, NO, NO!
Try the tape slot, maybe it's in there.
Zkus packu, mozna to bude tam.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works here, except where lines contain `!` characters.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
set "file=text.txt"
set "line="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (new.txt) do (
   if not defined line set "line=%%a"
      if not "!line!"=="%%a" (
         type "%file%" |repl "!line!" "%%a" L >temp.txt
         move temp.txt "%file%" >nul
         set "line="
      )
)
```